# Getting an SQL Exception 'NaN' is not a valid numeric or approximate numeric value

Tags: java, sql, json, nan

I'm having an SQL exception while i'm trying to parse a JSON object. Here's my code snippet.

```
public JSONArray paymentMode(String stringObjects) throws SQLException {

    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();

    //JSONOBJECT RETURN
    JSONObject jsonObjectReturn =  JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
    JSONObject obj = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
    JSONArray array = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray();
    Session session = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
    try {
        // test
        BeanLocator beanLocator = PortletBeanLocatorUtil
                .getBeanLocator("Mrcos-services-portlet");
        BasicDataSource bds = (BasicDataSource) beanLocator
                .locate("mrcosDataSourceTarget");
        conn = (Connection) bds.getConnection();

        jsonObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject(stringObjects);

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dataArray");


        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);



        callableStatement = (CallableStatement) conn
                .prepareCall("{call PaymentModeSPv2(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
        callableStatement.setString(1, jsonObject.getString("mode"));
        callableStatement.setString(2, jsonObject.getString("num1"));
        callableStatement.setString(3, jsonObject.getString("date1"));
        callableStatement.setString(4, jsonObject.getString("num2"));
        callableStatement.setString(5, jsonObject.getString("date2"));
        callableStatement.setString(6, jsonObject.getString("remarks"));
        callableStatement.setDouble(7, jsonObject.getDouble("amount"));
        callableStatement.setString(8, jsonObject.getString("receipt"));
        callableStatement.setString(9, jsonObject.getString("algo"));
        callableStatement.setString(10, jsonObject.getString("code"));
        callableStatement.setString(11, jsonObject.getString("address"));
        callableStatement.setString(12, jsonObject.getString("status"));
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(13, Types.INTEGER);

        callableStatement.executeQuery();

        String xreturn = callableStatement.getString(13);



        jsonObjectReturn =  JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
        jsonObjectReturn.put("xreturn", xreturn);

        array.put(jsonObjectReturn);    


        System.out.println("jsonObjectReturn : " + jsonObjectReturn);

        }
        return array;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (callableStatement != null) {
            callableStatement.close();
        }

        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
        closeSession(session);
    }

    jsonObjectReturn =  JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
    jsonObjectReturn.put("result", "NO RESULTS FOUND!");
    return array;

}
```

I'm having an error at **callableStatement.setDouble(7, jsonObject.getDouble("amount"));** saying **java.sql.SQLException: 'NaN' is not a valid numeric or approximate numeric value**.

The **amount** is decimal in my database. I also tried to use float instead of double but still gives the same error message. I also tried to pass an integer and a decimal number but still the same error occurs. Please help I'm stuck for a while now. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like "amount" Attribute do not contains a number. can you use a Debugger to find it out?

Comment: It sounds to me as if `jsonObject.getDouble("amount")` returns the String `"NaN"` and your DBMS can't parse that as a "number"

Comment: hi all. yes my jsonObject.getDouble("amount") is returning NaN everytime I input a number.. what should I do?

Comment: use the code of @tamas Rev in comments below

Comment: I tried using Tamas Rev codes below but still gives me an error..

Comment: is it working now @chiradee?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `javascript` `[NaN][1]` in `jsonObject.getDouble("amount")`. So you need to deal with it somehow. E.g. you can replace it with `0` or `Double.NaN`:

```
String amt = jsonObject.getString("amount");
Double amount = "NaN".equals(amt) ? Double.NaN : Double.parseDouble(amt);
callableStatement.setDouble(7, amount);
```

Comment: There is a special method like Double.isNaN

Comment: I don't know how this `JSONObject ` handles NaN-s. Probably a `Double.isNaN(jsonObject.getDouble("amount")) ? 0 : jsonObject.getDouble("amount")` would do too.

Comment: Hi @TamasRev, I tried your solution but I still got an error. **java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1020)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)**

Comment: your 2nd solution gave me **Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to boolean**

Comment: @chiradee what do you get with `jsonObject.getDouble("amount")`? Also, what do you get with `jsonObject.getString("amount")` ? These will help me to write a more accurate solution.